# Is there a solution to the extreme lag of Sonic 2006 on PS3?

Tags: technical-issues, ps3, sonic-the-hedgehog-2006

Is there any way to make the Sonic the Hedgehog game run smooth enough for decent play on the PS3?

It's unbearable, I've almost thrown the game out the window here. Every time a little bit of shadow comes on screen, Sonic goes into Matrix-style slow-motion, unintentionally I assume.

Perhaps somebody has made an update or a patch for the game?

Comment: Even if someone other the developers went out of their way do reverse engineer the PS3 version to make a custom patch, there's no way you could get it on the system without hacking it

Comment: You mean the port of the original from the Genesis?

Comment: No the first ps3 sonic game.

Comment: @Dreagan I have no idea what your talking about.

Comment: @Ender: please do a quick google of the first sonic ps3 game ('sonic the hedgehog').. or are you telling me you've played the ps3 version of the gae without any immense lag? If so, what version of ps3 are you using (I'm using first gen)?

Comment: @dreagan somehow i missed the release of this game, never knew it excisted.

Comment: @dreagan - Is this question about [Sonic The Hedgehog (2006)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_the_Hedgehog_%282006_video_game%29#Critical_reception)? I'm just wondering so I can retag it appropriately if so.

Comment: yes it is, retag away :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no exact way to do it but here are some options.

1. Delete the game from `Game Data Utility` and the `Saved Data Utility (PS3)` then re-install the game.
2. Go to settings and click `Game Settings` and turn OFF the `PS-Upscaler` and `PS-Smoothing`.
3. Make sure that there is nothing plugged into the USB ports.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your hd resoloution to 720p for it to work because if you put it to 1080p or 1080i it will make the game go slow motion and longer loading times